# UnboundedSolutionException using apache commons math SimplexSolver

Tags: java, math, linear-programming

I am working with `org.apache.commons.math3.optimization` specifically with `SimplexSolver` and I'm getting an `UnboundedSolutionException`.  The problem is I dont know what that means or what to do about it.

Where the following are the inputs:

```
double[] cliScores = new double[] {-0.6249277001180347};
LinearObjectiveFunction f = new LinearObjectiveFunction(cliScores,0.0);
Collection constraints = new ArrayList();
constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[]{1}, Relationship.LEQ, 769.3635211267606));
constraints.add(new LinearConstraint(new double[]{1}, Relationship.LEQ, 3.2466463287069885E-28));

PointValuePair solution = new SimplexSolver().optimize(f, constraints, GoalType.MAXIMIZE, false);
```

Everything up to the solution part looks right ... at least it matches up with the inputs that are expected.

Comment: If the problem is unbounded that means there is no max/min.  This can happen if the feasible set of points is unbounded.

Comment: If you have relatively few variables (e.g. 2) and only a few (<10) constraints, write them down and I will tell you if the feasible set is indeed unbounded.  Otherwise, it is hard to tell in general.

Comment: I don't have experience with SimplexSolver, but the above appears to be trying to maximize the function .5 subject to the condition that 1 < 3.  What are you really trying to do?

Comment: I edited the above with actual values ... it should be noted that in this instance the cliScores array has a lenght of 1 ... that will not always be the case

Comment: What are the constraints in "math" terms?  For example, is the first constraint x <= 769.36... and the second is x<= 3.2466...? And what are you trying to maximize? -0.6249...*x?  If these are all correct, then there is no maximum (make x very negative for example) because the feasible region is unbounded.